# jQuery Isotope filtering Issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

i am using jQuery Isotope to filter the Portofolio Section

My filters

```
      <div id="filters" class="portfolioSection">
        <ul>
          <li><a class="current" href="#" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-filter="category-1">Category 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-filter="category-2">Category 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-filter="category-3">Category 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Content Section

```
<div class="portfolioContent">
            <ul class="row">
              <li class="portfolio element category-1 category-2"><img src="img/project1.png">
                <div class="projectName">Project Name</div>
                <div class="projectCategory">Category 1</div>
              </li>
              <li class="portfolio element category-3"><img src="img/project2.png">
                <div class="projectName">Project Name</div>
                <div class="projectCategory">Category 1</div>
              </li>
              <li class="portfolio element category-3"><img src="img/project3.png">
                <div class="projectName">Project Name</div>
                <div class="projectCategory">Category 1</div>
              </li>
              <li class="portfolio element category-3"><img src="img/project4.png">
                <div class="projectName">Project Name</div>
                <div class="projectCategory">Category 1</div>
              </li>
              <li class="portfolio element category-1 category-3"><img src="img/project5.png">
                <div class="projectName">Project Name</div>
                <div class="projectCategory">Category 1</div>
              </li>
              <li class="portfolio element category-2"><img src="img/project6.png">
                <div class="projectName">Project Name</div>
                <div class="projectCategory">Category 1</div>
              </li>
              <li class="portfolio element category-1 category-2"><img src="img/project7.png">
                <div class="projectName">Project Name</div>
                <div class="projectCategory">Category 1</div>
              </li>
              <li class="portfolio element category-2"><img src="img/project8.png">
                <div class="projectName">Project Name</div>
                <div class="projectCategory">Category 1</div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

My Jquery Code:

```
var $container = $('.portfolioContent');
// initialize isotope
$container.isotope({
  // options...
    itemSelector : '.portfolio',
  //layoutMode : 'fitRows'
});

// filter items when filter link is clicked
$('#filters a').click(function(){
  var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
  $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
  return false;
});
```

When i click Anything other than All all the content disappears.
And also the effect of smooth transition is missing.

Link: http://play.mink7.com/sophiance/  Click the View Section

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is slightly wrong:

```
<li><a href="#" data-filter="category-1">Category 1</a></li>
```

Should be:

```
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".category-1">Category 1</a></li>
```

notice the `.` before the class name

From the [Isotope documentation](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/filtering.html)

Comment: omg :P thanks a lot. i tried that. it works. any idea abt transition... updated the link

Comment: You save my day buddy! Thanks!